# Отсутствует зелёный огонек в вопросе с подтвержденным ответом

Tags: поддержка, ответы, принятые-ответы

[Следующий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898752/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5/898757#898757) имеет подтверждение от участника задавшего его. Мой вывод был сделан исходя из стоявшей галочки под одним из ответов.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. я так же давал ответ на этот вопрос, он присутствует в списке моих ответов

> [image: Ответ в списке]

**Вопрос.**

Почему в списке моих ответов, данный вопрос не имеет подтверждения? 
[image: Зеленый огонек]

Comment: Ну так галочка не на вашем же ответе

Comment: Зеленый загорается только тогда, когда подтвержденный ответ мой? Не тогда, когда в вопросе подтвержден ответ любым из участников.

Comment: @Kyper именно так, зеленым в профиле подсвечиваются только принятые ответы

Comment: @yolosora, Ваш ответ имеет несколько смыслов) Я понял, как-то сейчас не привычно, я ожидал там увидеть вопрос без принятого ответа

Comment: @Kyper ну так это список ответов, а не список вопросов

Comment: Сейчас уже проясняется почему зеленым горит ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [списке ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers) заливка (белая или зелёная) и число соответствуют именно указанному ответу. Т.е. его рейтинг и факт выбранности автором вопроса в качестве принятого (т.е. поставлена ли галочка). В частности такой подход позволяет различать ситуации, когда на один вопрос дано несколько ответов одним и тем же участником. Например, в моём профиле на Мете в списке ответов можно увидеть такую картину:

> [image: ответы в профиле]

Т.е. я дал три разных ответа на один и тот же вопрос, при этом видно, что ответ с рейтингом 6 является принятым.